# Mysqli Insert Command not Working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a database named "kargo" and a table named "cargos". I tried the code below but the data from the `POST` are not added to the "cargos" table. The connection is fine and returns no errors. What can I do?

```
<?php include("functions.php"); get_header(); ?>
<div id="content">
<?php $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','kargo');
$name = $_POST['c_name'];
$c_texit = $_POST['c_texit'];
$c_tarrive = $_POST['c_tarrive'];
$target = "kargo/";
$target_file = $_FILES["cpic"]["tmp_name"];
$target_move = $target.$_FILES["cpic"]["name"];
$uploadOk = 1 ;

if (file_exists($target_move)) {
$uploadOk = 0; } 

if($uploadOk == 1 ) {
$query = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO cargos 
VALUES(NULL,'".$name."','".$c_texit."','".$c_tarrive."','".$target_move."')");
move_uploaded_file($target_file,$target_move);
echo "Cargo added."; header( "refresh:5;url=panel.php" ); }
else { echo "-"; header( "refresh:5;url=panel.php" ); } ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: may be `VALUES(NULL` should be `VALUES (NULL`

Comment: tried, nothing happened

Comment: First thing to do would be to check your error logs and turn error reporting on using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your file. You should also use indentation to help spot syntax errors in the future more easily. You also need to tell us **the desired behaviour** rather than just "it doesn't work"

Comment: added "echo error_reporting(E_ALL);" that before "?>" tag. returned  32767

Comment: _'doesn't work'_ is not a problem description. _'returns no errors'_ - how would you know? There's not a single error check anywhere in this code.

Comment: Can you share your table column count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check your data type you are using in every column and also the `NOT NULL` and other limitations if the data you inserted matches to the table cargos.

If you use localhost, you can check the error by executing that mysqli command to the phpmyadmin.

---

You can also use `mysqli_error()` function to check whether the SQL has an error.

Example:

```
$query = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO cargos VALUES(NULL,'".$name."','".$c_texit."','".$c_tarrive."','".$target_move."')"))
if($mysqli->query($query) === FALSE)
    {
       mysqli_error($mysqli);   // generate SQL error message.
    }
    else
    {
       // execute something...
    }
```

Comment: i get that error on phpmyadmin, thanks pal.
" Column 'id' cannot be null "